# how to check if a spcific url is alreayd in the $templateCache in angular

Tags: caching, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Is there a way to check if a given url is already present in AngularJS' $templateCache ?

To provide a bit of context : I made a directive that inserts a loader while waiting for ngInclude templateUrl to be loaded, then plays an animation, and I'd like that animation not to play if the content was simply retrieved from the cache and not fetched from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code to check if url is present in templatecache

```
$templateCache.get('stringurl');
```

Comment: thanks, I was trying that but on an expression. adding a scope.$eval(myExpr) did the trick once I was sure this was supposed to work.